# Cordova InAppBrowser can't interact with some websites (iOS)

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I have a rather strange issue with the InAppBrowser plugin on iOS.

When I create an empty/new cordova project and add the InAppBrowser Plugin to open a link (target = _blank), it works as expected. The IAB opens and the website is loaded and works as intended. I can click all the elements and dropdowns.

But when I do the same in a much, much larger (Angular 1.x) app: The IAB opens and the website loads but I can't really click or interact with the elements on it. Focus style changes are sometimes triggered and sometimes I can even select an element but often nothing happens at all when I click a button, link or dropdown.

Strangely this does not affect all websites that I load in the IAB. But when I open the same page in Safari it works fine.

//Edit: 
I was analyze this further. It does not appear to be a negative interaction with a cordova plugin but actually with the JS app currently running.

Comment: The elements in the website which you are opening with IAB should support the safari browser. First open the website in the Safari browser and check.

Comment: I've experienced a similar issue yesterday. I can click select dropdowns to show the options, but I can't close the dropdown; It's open forever. Strangely, the website works perfectly in safari on same iPhone. I'm using InAppBrowser + iPhone + angular 1.x website.

Comment: @RaghavendraRao I of course tested that. The website runs perfectly fine in Safari.